Why do I get a segmentation fault when the string has been properly initialized?
This is a cs50 Recover problem. I am trying to submit the code. However, I get segmentation faults. I am not sure how as I have initialized the string by setting it to zero. The initialization has been done just above the while loop.
This is my code. I would appreciate any help on this issue as I am very new to programming.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Accept a single command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover FILE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the memory card
    FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (card ==NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened");
        return 2;
    }

    // Create a buffer for a block of data
    uint8_t buffer[512];


    int counter = 0; //This is to count the numebr of JPEG files read
    FILE *img = NULL; // I need to initialize this now because in the whil loop,
    //I am closing the output file first and then updating filename.

    char filename[8] = {0};  //This is to allocate memory for the string name.

     // While there's still data left to read from the memory card
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, card) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        //I dont need to write&buffer as the C program automatically assumes that it should take the address
        //of first elemnet of the buffer array.
        {
            if (counter != 0)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }

            sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", counter);

            if (counter != 0)
            {

                img = fopen(filename,"w");
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(card);
    fclose(img);
}


Adding some "printf" statements as a simplified debug method would point out that the output "image" files are never opened for writing due to the "counter" variable never being incremented.  Thus, when the input file reading is completed, closing the "img" file handle is giving your program the program segmentation fault.
Following is a snippet of your code with some added "printf" statements providing some debug information.
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, card) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            //I dont need to write&buffer as the C program automatically assumes that it should take the address
            //of first elemnet of the buffer array.
        {
            if (counter != 0)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }

            sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", counter);

            printf("File name: %s\n", filename);

            if (counter != 0)   /* This test will stay false, so no file gets created for writing   */
            {
                img = fopen(filename,"w");
                printf("img value %p\n", img);  /* Note - this point is not reached                 */
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Closing up\n");     /* Just checking that this point is reached */
    fclose(card);
    fclose(img);                /* Since "img" is undefined, the segmentation fault occurs          */

Calling this program resulted in the following output denoting the point where the segmentation fault occurs.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/recover/bin/Release$ ./recover a1335.jpg
File name: 000.jpg
Closing up
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The key bits that I wanted to point out are:

You may want to comfortable with utilizing a debugger to track down issues in programs that have issues such as segmentation faults.
If initially you don't want to utilize a debugger tool, sprinkling code with "printf" statements can also provide a simplified method of zeroing in to points of issue.

For sure, the code does need to be evaluated and revised to properly test and utilize the "counter" variable, but mainly I wanted to address methods to troubleshoot code that has undefined behavior, and probably search out and review additional "C" tutorials.
